# How to combine multiple columns while adding categorical variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a bar plot, and currently my data looks like this:

tree  flower  shrub
4     4       4
5     3       2
4     1       3

I want the column names to be x-values, and the mean of each column to be represented by a separate bar. I think the best way to get at this would be to change my data so it looks like this:

plant  value
tree   4
tree   5
tree   4
flower 4
flower 3
flower 1
shrub  4
shrub  2
shrub  3

Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Or have any other suggestions for building a bar plot based on this data?

Comment: hi nick, the example of datat you provided is not a reproducible example. users here should be able to run your code to reproduce your result. you need to provide a dataset or a subset of it. I would recommend using dput() function. Also, include the attempts you made to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `stack` from `base R`

```
setNames(stack(df1)[2:1], c('plant', 'value'))
```